# How to match gestures with kinect v2?

Tags: kinect, gesture, kinect-v2

I am planning to develop a web app which recognizes user hand gesture(thumb up and thumb down) and perform basic functions(like updating a value). how to accomplish this with kinect v2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know about visual gesture builder?

Visual Gesture Builder (VGB) generates data that applications use to perform gesture detection at run time.
Basically you can use the data it generates to perform gesture recognition like swipe up, wave, hands up etc...

Steps:

1. Record in Kinect studio 2 the position you want the pose to be.
2. open up Visual gesture builder to train your clips( selection of the clip that is correct)
3. build the vgbsln in the visual gesture builder to produce a gbd file( this will be imported into your project as the file that the `gesturedetector.cs` will read and implement into your project.
4. code out your own logic on what will happen when user have matching poses in the `gestureresultview.cs`.

Here is a video you must watch to help get you started in building application with kinect, [This video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/k4wdev/Custom-Gestures-End-to-End-with-Kinect-and-Visual-Gesture-Builder)

It will teach you the process i mentioned above. really do replay it again and again as that is what i did.

I have a WPF application that can detect several gestures such as swipe up, hands up, swipe left etc... you can do your own testing by pulling my project on [github here.](https://github.com/bingcheng45/Kinect-Swipe-Test)

However, I do not have experience on implementing the gestures on a web application yet. But you can start by learning how to work with the kinect first :D

Do let me know if you find my help useful and select this as the answer to your problems XP

Comment: Thanks a lot for your guidance. Your answer was really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: glad to help! :D